# regrouping a variable in R

Tags: r

I am working with NLS data and want to run a logistic regression of marital status on a few independent variables. 
Marital status is coded the following way: 
    1084       1 Never married, cohabiting 
    2441       2 Never married, not cohabiting 
    2744       3 Married, spouse present 
     188       4 Married, spouse absent 
      18       5 Separated, cohabiting 
      66       6 Separated, not cohabiting 
     202       7 Divorced, cohabiting 
     361       8 Divorced, not cohabiting 
       4       9 Widowed, cohabiting 
      12      10 Widowed, not cohabiting

I want just to make 2 groups of married and never married, where group 1 and 2 will be summed up to married=0 and the rest married=1. My dataset is called nlsy. 
I know it is a basic question but I would appreciate any help. 
Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example] when you are asking a question. Also state clear with an example of what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like (substituting in the actual variables names, as you did not provide a minimum reproducible example):

```
nlsy$never_married <- nlsy$marital_status %in% c("1084 1 Never married, cohabiting", "2441 2 Never married, not cohabiting")
```

This will make a column of your data.frame (supposing nlsy is a data.frame) that is a logical value, `TRUE` if never married, `FALSE` if ever married.

Comment: I ended up doing the following, it is not pretty but it seems to work: nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 1 ] <- 0
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 2 ] <- 0
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 3 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 4 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 5 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 6 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 7 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 8 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 9 ] <- 1
nlsy$married[ nlsy$married == 10 ] <- 1

Answer (score 0):

Use this. There is nothing wrong with what you did but that is a long method.

```
install.packages("dplyr")  
library(dplyr)  

a <- cbind.data.frame(status=c("Never married, cohabiting","Never married, not cohabiting","Married, spouse present",
         "Married, spouse absent","Separated, cohabiting","Separated, not cohabiting",
         "Divorced, cohabiting","Divorced, not cohabiting","Widowed, cohabiting",
         "Widowed, not cohabiting"), value=c(1084 ,2441,2744,188,18,66,202,361,4,12))

a=a %>%
  mutate(married_status=as.numeric(status %in% 
                        c("Married, spouse present",
         "Married, spouse absent","Separated, cohabiting","Separated, not cohabiting",
         "Divorced, cohabiting","Divorced, not cohabiting","Widowed, cohabiting",
         "Widowed, not cohabiting"))) %>%
select(-status)
```

Let me know in case of any queries.